# Is storing data directly in a list node better than storing a pointer to data?

Tags: architecture, data-structures, performance, list, linked-list

Suppose we have two different doubly-linked list structures:

1. One has content of the node embedded directly in the node:

   ```
   struct Content {
       // some stuff
   };
   struct Node {
       struct Node *next;
       struct Node *prev;
       struct Content content;
   }
   ```
2. The other has a pointer to content:

   ```
   struct Content;
   struct Node {
       struct Node *next;
       struct Node *prev;
       struct Content *content;
   }
   ```

What are considerations to prefer one option to the other? The points can be about everything: performance in different conditions, architecture, ease of modification, ease of manipulating the list, etc.

I'd like to gather knowledge about the trade-offs present.

Shown code is `C`, but the question also applies to `C++`, or any other language which has explicit pointers.

Comment: The advantages of using pointers in a linked list, tree or other data structure are the same as the advantages of using pointers in any other context.  Pointers to data significantly improve performance for repetitive operations such as traversing strings, lookup tables, control tables and tree structures. In particular, it is often much cheaper in time and space to copy and dereference pointers than it is to copy and access the data to which the pointers point.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: Some Gnome software changed to using GObject and GList, many years ago. The resulting 64-bit bloat from 10 MB RAM usage to 150 MB disgusted me.  That was a 15X growth! For a RSS reader! Point is, try using a simple vector or array of the Content. No list. No pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Critical Path: Element Traversal

Let's say your most critical loops sequentially iterate through a list and access `Content`. In that case, typically in descending order of efficiency and ascending order of flexibility:

**1. Intrusive C-Style List Node**

The highest performance and least amount of flexibility is often going to go to the "classic" C-style intrusive linked list backed by a fixed allocator. The list pointers and contents are inseparably tied together, yielding a very inflexible (but often most compact) solution, like so:

```
struct ContentNode {
    // The content data is *directly* embedded here (either below or above
    // these pointers for optimal alignment at the cost of minimal padding).
    struct ContentNode *prev;
    struct ContentNode *next;
};
```

This is only sometimes more efficient than `2` below while *always* being far less flexible. It only provides a benefit over the second solution if you can reduce the amount of padding by directly embedding the contents into the list node itself.

The level of flexibility lost here is enormous as the notion of element and list node fuse into one inseparable, tightly-bundled concept. And it's also quite dumb to use (in my strong opinion) unless you are first using a fixed allocator to give back a lot of the spatial locality that linked structures generally lack.

Yet the most performance-critical areas of a codebase will often be looking at elements that are aggregated into one primary data structure (possibly with auxiliary data structures pointing to them, but still one *main* data structure). In that case, your profiling/tuning sessions might have you ultimately reaching for this kind of very-inflexible solution in some very isolated, performance-critical section of your codebase.

**2. Non-Intrusive, Contiguous List Node**

This would be like your first version, and is dramatically more flexible as `Content` and `Node` do not have to be inseparable (`Content` could be stored in other data structures that own its memory, e.g.).

```
struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Content content;
}
```

This only costs more than `1` in the rare event that it results in more padding, yet is *always* more flexible as it decouples `Content` from the linked list representation.

**3. Disjointed List Node**

This describes your second solution and tends to be the least efficient as a result of additional cache misses, page faults, and the need for an additional pointer to be stored (more memory usage overall).

```
struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Content *content;
}
```

Yet this is the easiest way to achieve flexibility, especially in C if you turn `content` into a void pointer, as you can generalize your linked list very easily this way. Another way to generalize is to use variable-length structs.

**Fixed Allocator**

In these cases, where performance is a top priority and the critical paths of the list iterate through list elements and access them, it's insane not to use a fixed allocator.

The biggest immediate performance concern of linked lists in cases where the nodes/elements are smallish in size is the loss of contiguity ("disjointed memory") which translates to at least more compulsory cache misses and page faults and possibly even more non-compulsory ones as well.

The fixed allocator is an easy "reach-around" solution when you are inevitably stuck with a linked structure to dramatically reduce cache misses/page faults.

**"Efficient"**

It's worth noting that the differences between these diminish if the size of the `Content` data fields are really large. They show up the most if `Content` is really small (ex: 16 bytes, maybe 64 bytes, not 400 bytes). If `Content` is huge (hundreds of bytes or more), then the differences start to become increasingly moot as well as the need for a fixed allocator.

### Critical Path: List Manipulation

Let's say, instead, that your most critical paths of execution don't even inspect `Content` data fields and just manipulate list pointers.

In that case, the tables turn. Now `3` becomes the most efficient solution as a result of hot/cold field splitting (`Content` fields becomes cold data, rarely accessed, and the list pointers become hot data, frequently accessed).

In this case, you still want to use a fixed allocator pooling chunks of data from contiguous pooled memory for the `Node` (don't have to for `Content` quite as much here given that it's cold) to reduce page faults and cache misses (at least compulsory ones even if you end up totally rearranging the list).

When combined with the fixed allocator and the hot/cold field splitting, now more nodes can be allocated and accessed without triggering further page faults/cache misses as a result of the smaller size per node (with the cold `Content` data being stored elsewhere).

All the dynamics here are going to be related to memory efficiency with respect to the memory hierarchy. If you want to get the most out of your linked structures (trees and linked lists), then this is the place to study.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the contents of the Context structure. If it contains less data than is the size of a pointer on your architecture, then the memory is wasted, because the size of the pointer + payload is more than twice as large as the payload itself.

Another problem might be memory access. When you access the data through a pointer, memory has to be read twice, first to retrieve the location and once more to get the actual data. Since it can be stored anywhere in memory, it is unlikely that it got cached with the node itself. However if you worry about performance you shouldn't be using lists in the first place.

If you have a larger context structure, which it is not created at the same time, or for any other reason can't be created with the node itself then the pointers are superior, because you don't have to copy all the data to the node. In any other case it doesn't really matter, because most common operations on lists like sorting, inserting, removing, only modify the next and previous pointers, not the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be rare in practice to actually have the option. The decision will likely be made for you simply by the requirements of the application. The semantics of your two examples are very different. It's a typical [by-value or by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) decision. I think you just need to ask

```
Content myContent;
myContent.Value = "Some content";

Node myNode;
myNode.Content = myContent; // or myNode.Content = &myContent;
myNode.Content.Value = "Different content";
```

At this point, what would you expect myContent.Value to be? Should changing the value in the list change the original object?